dndkit (React): Cancel drag and drop
In dndkit (https://dndkit.com/), I need to be able to cancel a drag when a certain event happens (ex. change of props). I can't seem to find any way to do that in the documentations. I am missing something, or is it really impossible?
The only way I have found to trigger a cancel is with a keyboard event (Keyboard sensor). It is not what I want.
